# What is the equivalent of "client.accept_invite" from discord.py in discord.py rewrite?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I can't find anything that serves this purpose in the docs. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

The functionality was deprecated and has been removed.  From [the migration guide](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/migrating.html):

> - `Client.accept_invite`
>
>   - There is no replacement for this one. This functionality is deprecated API wise.

Comment: How might I substitute this in my code then? Is the API functionality still intact on discord's part?

Comment: The discord API has deprecated it, which means that at some point they're going to turn it off and you've already been warned. You could look at the implementation in the older discord.py versions and write your own version to use until then: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/async/discord/client.py#L2703